# Angular controller functions won't work from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys I have a small issue, I am trying to call some functions form a controller declared inside a directive like so:

```
var homepage = angular.module('homepage');

homepage.directive('searchServices', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.services = config.services;
            $scope.currentService = $scope.services[0];

            $scope.clickMe = function() {
                console.log('xxxxx');
            }

            $scope.setCurrentService = function (service) {
                console.log(service);
                return service == $scope.currentService;
            }

            $scope.setNewService = function (e, service) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(service);
                $scope.currentService = service;
            }
        }],
        template: [
            '<li ng-repeat="service in services"',
                 'ng-click="clickMe()"',
                 'ng-class="{active:setCurrentService(currentService)}">',
                 '<a href="#">',
                     '{{currentService}}',
                     '<span class="icons-{{service}}"></span>',
                      '{{service}}',
                 '</a>',
            '</li>'].join('')
    }    
}]);
```

But it seems that nothing is happening when I call the functions in the template.. I am sure I am missing something... but what ?

Comment: you will have to compile the template to get the angular directives working inside other directive template

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with this. I created [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/852/) with same code. Its working except that I have hardcoded `config.services`. Please check if there is error before the event function `clickMe` is assigned to `$scope`. [I also added item `restrict: 'E'` to the directive definition]

Comment: Well this is what is weird it should work.. I have no errors, but if I remove the scope it works

Comment: it's not that... @wonderbell, it works on the fiddle... weird

Comment: I know why it works in the fiddle youi've added angular 1.0.0, if you add angular 1.5.5 (latest) it reproduces

Answer (score 0):

The answer was scope: false, dunno why :)